# Testing arguments going into batch file that contains spaces

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I've got a problem testing an input argument (%1) to a batch file when the argument contains spaces.  Naturally I call the batch file by placing the argument inside quotes but annoyingly the quotes are also passed into the argument causing a problem.

Here is my example bat file which checks to see if an argument is provided, display an error and exit if no argument provided or does some "processing" if the argument exists:

```
@echo off
if "%1"=="" goto missingarg

echo Processing %1
goto end

:missingarg
echo ERROR: Argument missing

:end
```

If I call my batch program without an argument then `"%1"` resolves to `""` and the check on line 2 works as planned and jumps to the `missingarg` label, displays the error and exists.

However, if I call my batch program with an argument that contains spaces e.g.

> mybatch.bat "C:\Projects\File with spaces.txt"

then I get the error: "**with** was unexpected at this time.".  This is because line 2 resolves to: `if ""C:\Projects\File with spaces.txt""=="" goto missingarg`. The quotes are included causing double quotes.

I can't change line 2 to `if %1=""` as then a missing argument causes an error because `if =="" goto missingarg` is equally invalid.

How do I strip the outer quotes or stop the outer quotes from being passed in?  Thanks

Comment: It is better to use ```if "%~1"==""```, as `%1` may already be doublequoted, and the `~` will remove any outer surrounding quotes from it. If you don't do that you may and up with `if ""my string""=="my string"` which will never be true.

Answer (score 0):

So I should use `%~1` instead of `%1` to strip surrounding quotes from argument